# reloadData method not working - table is null

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a method in my NSTableViewDelegate class to reload the data table from an external class:

```
- (void)reloadTable {

    NSLog(@"reload data %@", table);
    [table reloadData];
}
```

when I try to call this method from an external class, the table that is trying to be reloaded is null:

```
reload data (null)
```

I am calling this method with the following code in another class:

```
TableController *delegate = [[TableController alloc] init];
[delegate reloadTable];
```

Now, I would think this would be because I am init'ing a new instance of a table controller and calling the method on that instance of the table controller. So in my `reloadTable` method, I use `self.table` instead of table - this has the same results:

```
reload data (null)
```

In the .xib, dataSource and delegate are set to the TableController class. I suppose it should be noted that I am using a view-based tableview and I not using bindings. What am I missing?

EDIT: From these answers, it appears these issues may be caused because this class is just the datasource and delegate for the table view. Should I create a new class that is a ViewController for the TableView? Would I be correct in saying the class that exists would be the "Model" class and the new class I would create would be the "Controller" class in MVC?

EDIT 2: I created a TableViewController class and set the "view" outlet to my tableview in "Panel.xib". In another class that I need to reload the table from, I do as follows:

```
 TableViewController *tv = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Panel" bundle:nil];
 [tv.table reloadData];
```

No error is generated, but the table view does not reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `-initWithNibName:bundle:` to create your ViewController.

Comment: would this be complicated by the fact that the table view is in a .xib that is already loaded and that .xib belongs to another class?

Comment: @rick possibly, but I don't think so. It *should* work just fine, give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: updated the original question, still not working. Is this what you were suggesting?